How keep database credentials?
I have a Quarkus java app and using this Dockerfile
    # Use a base image with JDK 17
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory in the Docker container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven build output (fat jar) into the Docker image
COPY target/quarkus-app/ /app

# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to execute the Quarkus application
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/quarkus-run.jar"]

my app uses Github actions for building and deploying to azure web app
now I have database credentials securely passing problem and also have auth client id and secret for Authentication, we can use KeyVault for them ,but don't understand how and should I pass them to Dockerfile like this or not ?
this I got from chat gpt and it didn't include client id and secret
    # Use a base image with JDK 17
FROM openjdk:17

# Set the working directory in the Docker container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven build output (fat jar) into the Docker image
COPY target/quarkus-app/ /app

# Expose the port your application runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Set environment variables for database URL, username, and password
ENV DB_URL=""
ENV DB_USERNAME=""
ENV DB_PASSWORD=""

# Command to execute the Quarkus application
CMD ["java", "-Dquarkus.datasource.url=${DB_URL}", "-Dquarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}", "-Dquarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}", "-jar", "/app/quarkus-run.jar"]

and this is application.properties
quarkus.datasource.url=${DB_URL}
quarkus.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
quarkus.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}

I'm not clear how to do this where to pass client id and secret and how these parameters are gonna be filled maybe during deploy.yaml deploy to azure web app i should declare env ?
Please any clarification or example would be great

You should use secrets in GitHub Actions and map them to environment variables
steps:
  - name: Hello world action
    env: # Or as an environment variable
      super_secret: ${{ secrets.DB_URL }}
    run: |
      docker build --build-arg DB_URL=$super_secret 

of course you should do for the task where those variables need to be used.
Take a look on the documentation here
In the docker use arguments
ARG DB_URL
ARG DB_USERNAME
ARG DB_PASSWORD
# Set environment variables for database URL, username, and password
ENV DB_URL="${DB_URL}"
ENV DB_USERNAME="${DB_USERNAME}"
ENV DB_PASSWORD="${DB_PASSWORD}"


but this way i will keep them in github secrets right maybe I can keep them in azure web app env variables?

Where do you build you docker? I gave you solution with GitHub Actions because you provided docker file. If you use only in code, and tour secrets are just needed on runtime then of course use this in Azure Web App env. But if you need those values on build time it will not work with Azure Web App envs.

yes thank you i did it with azure Vault secrets and during runtime it was filled,thanks.
